# grep -r (recursive), remove/hide all directories

Tags: grep

Noob here - I want to run `grep -r asdf` however, **I only want unique matches in my directories** (i.e. disregarding any directory, display unique matches only).

So I ran `grep -r asdf | sort --unique`. However - this does not work since the directory names are different (`dir1/a.txt asdf` and `dir2/a.txt asdf`).

I didn't see an option (I tried e.g. `grep -riol`) to exclude directories and I guess that barely makes sense for the scope of the function. Can I somehow cut-away the directories and only show the matched filename + match (possibly without a mind/universe-bending regex/sed/...)?

Comment: Do I understand correctly: The files `dir1/a.txt` and `dir2/a.txt` are the same and you want only `a.txt` as a result?

Comment: I see, you want `a.txt:asdf`, right?

Comment: @pLumo precisely, last comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
grep -r abcd | awk -F ':' '{gsub(/.*\//,"",$1) }1' | awk '!seen[$1]++'
```

- `gsub` will remove directory structure.
      `(/.*\//,"",$1)` will remove("") all(.*) before the last match of '/' in first field($1).
- `!seen[$1]++` will uniq the filename.

Note: directory name must not have `:` in it.

Comment: can you briefly explain the awk regex?

Comment: check the description...

Comment: This doesn't work properly for me. if the string is in the middle or it contains : it gets buggy somehow, can't make out where exactly this fails

Answer (score 1):

I think with the default capabilities of `grep` there in no way of doing this.

You could go with something like this, which is  just a "small" regex:

```
grep -r asdf | sed '#^.*/##' | sort --unique
```

Note: This approach will not work if the search-pattern contains a `/`

Answer (score 1):

This groups by basename and grep output:

```
   ]# grep -ro '#include' include/ |sed -E 's|.*/(.*:)|\1|' |uniq -c |sort|tail -n7
         28 kvm_host.h:#include
         28 mm.h:#include
         29 ib_verbs.h:#include
         31 net_namespace.h:#include
         32 sock.h:#include
         44 fs.h:#include
         48 drmP.h:#include
```

I used `grep -o` to get some duplicates. Same time it leaves out the slashes...

If the names contain `:` the sed will not work correctly. The regex first throws away everything until the last `/`, then stores everything until a `:` as `\1`.

I used `-E` because of the (subexpression) and `|` because of the slash.

---

The subexpression `(.*:)` is a bit simple (will fail if a grepped line contains a colon). If you leave out the colon, it will fail when the line contains a slash.

---

Looking at this output I say **this is impossible** in theory (to parse grep's output in that way):

```
]# grep -r "" d*
d:/ir:/afile...in file "d"
d:/ir:/afile...in file "ir"
```

**This is identical.** I needed a dir with a colon at the end and a file with overlapping name and contents.

```
]# ls d* 
d

'd:':
ir
```

`grep --color` makes the difference!

---

The `include` directory is the one from the linux kernel source. One full line in one include-file looks like this.

```
]# grep -rH '#incl' include/linux/aio.h 
include/linux/aio.h:#include <linux/aio_abi.h>
```

Comment: grep: include/: No such file or directory, sorry if I didn't use the syntax right... I also never saw a ]# before

Comment: I have the same problem: ls dir1/ ls: cannot access 'dir1/': No such file or directory

Comment: PS1=']# ' is how I set my geometrical prompt: no letters. The dollar sign looks too much like an "S" to me. I have enough things to read on my screen.

Comment: I'm running this on raspbian, is this the issue @kernel?

Answer (score 1):

With `perl -pe 's|.*?([^/]*:)|\1|'` it seems to work with colons and slashes in the files (content, not name!). Two lines below have both.

```
]# grep -r ':' include |head -n3 | perl -pe 's|.*?([^/]*:)|\1|'
cistpl.h:/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only */
ss.h:/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only */
ss.h: * are three options:
```

---

Is this mind-bending? The idea seems simple:

Keep all non-slash chars in front of the first colon.

The regex `|.*?([^/]*:)|` has these parts:

- `.*?` match anything, but **as little as possible**, then...
- `([^/]*:)` this subexpression which is...
- `[^/]*:` as much **non-slash** as possible, and then colon.

---

At least it bends in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

With output from `grep --null`, the following GNU `awk` program should work with any filename:

```c
BEGIN {
    # OFS will be printed between
    # each filename and matched line
        OFS = ":"

    # Use null-byte as a record separator
    # to use with output from grep --null
        RS = "\0"

    # Apart from the first record,
    # everything up to the first newline
    # of a record is the matched line from grep
    # Everything after first newline is a filename
        FPAT = "^[^\n]*|\n.*$"

}
NR == 1 {
    # Entire first record
    # is the first filename
    # set `file` to the basename
        file = gensub(".*/","",1)
        next
}
! seen[file, $1]++ {
    # If filename+match
    # not seen, print it
        print file, $1
}
{
    # Get basename of file
    # from next match
        file = gensub(".*/","",1,$2)
}
```

---

```
grep --null -rF asdf . | awk -f see_above.gawk
```